# Graphics Problem on older Laptop (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04, graphics

I am trying to get Ubuntu 18.04 to run on an older laptop that is to nice to be thrown away.

Specs:
Nvidia Geforce GT 130M
Intel Core 2 duo
17" Screen

The problem manifests itself in a black screen after the purple loading screen at startup. This also happens with the live CD effectively preventing installation.

I tried to circumvent this problem as follows:

I removed the quite and splash boot options and could see that the problem occurs after graphics was changed from VESA VGA to nouveau.
Using the nouveau.modeset=0 option (according to the internet preferable to nomodeset) I managed to install Ubuntu.
Unfortunately this leaves me with the same boot problem that can be circumvented using nouveau.modeset=0) resulting in a resolution of 640x... Pixels (and all around bad graphics).
To amend this issue I installed updates and the driver proposed by the Ubuntu driver tool (nvidia-340).
This leaves me with a system that has a similar black screen problem as I started out with. ADDITIONALLY I am unable to fix it because this black screen does also appear in the recovery mode accessed via boot options presented in GRUB.

This leaves me with a system that needs a reinstall (already done to test lightdm - got recommendation in IRC) or a repair from a liveCD. And I am out of Ideas to try/google so any input is highly appreciated :)

update:
Since I haven't heard back I did some experimentation and found out that earlier point releases of Ubuntu 16.04 (e.g. 16.04.01) still work on this machine however installing upgrades or using a later point release (e.g. 16.04.05) leads to the problems described above. 
I thought about burning 3-4 Ubuntu DVD's to narrow down the problem but I am unsure whether this would help.